# My dynamic drop down menu does not display my information from my mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-applications

I am trying to create a dynamic drop down menu when the user selects his state month, and the year  it searches  mysql data base that extracts the correct  information that  goes with State, month  and year.  When I Click the submit button  nothing happens, I also do not receive any errors on the screen.

I would appreciate any advice you could give me and or websites that might have the information that I need. If I should do it some other way please let me know.

```
    <?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('members/connectvars.php');

// Connect to the database
  $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if (!$dbc) {
    trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());


        if($_POST)
        {
        $state = $_POST['state']; 
        $month = $_POST['month']; 
        $year = $_POST['year']; 


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM triathlons WHERE state = '".$state."' month     ='".$month."' year = '".$year."' ") or die(mysql_error());

$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo "$num results found!<br>";

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$day = $result['day'];
$date = $result['date'];
$city= $result['city'];
$racename= $result['racename'];
$park= $result['park'];
$website= $result['website'];


echo "<b> day</b> : $day<br>
<b>Last Name : </b> $date<br>
<b>city : </b>$city<br>
<b>state : </b>$state <br><br>";
}
}


} 
?>

 <form  method="POST" id="filtermainpage" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

      <label for="state">State:</label>
        <select name="state" id="state1">



        <option selected="selected" value="">All States</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
          <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
          <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="DC">D.C.</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="FL" >Florida</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="ME">Maine</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
          <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MT">Montana</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
          <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="UT">Utah</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WA">Washington</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

        </select>

    </p>
    <br
    <br

      <label for="month">Month:</label>
        <select name="month" id="month1">

        <option selected="selected" value="0">All Months</option>
          <option value="1">January</option>
          <option value="2">February</option>
          <option value="3">March</option>
          <option value="4">April</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
          <option value="6">June</option>
          <option value="7">July</option>
          <option value="8">August</option>
          <option value="9">September</option>
          <option value="10">October</option>
          <option value="11">November</option>
          <option value="12">December</option>

      </select>


      <label for="year">Year:</label>
      <select name="year" id="year1">
          <option value="2013">2013</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
          <option value="2011">2011</option>


      </select>
      </label>
      </p>


    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="submit">
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: I don't get it. The if($_POST) is inside the if (!$dbc). Is this a mistake or is it just me who do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (!$dbc) {
        trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

            if($_POST) {
                $state = $_POST['state']; 
                $month = $_POST['month']; 
                $year = $_POST['year']; 
    [...]
```

The first if should probably be closed before the checking if post was sent. Otherwise nothing will happen when you successfully connect to the db. So instead:

```
    if (!$dbc) {
        trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    else if ($_POST) {
         $state = $_POST['state']; 
         $month = $_POST['month']; 
         $year = $_POST['year']; 
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start using the PDO class !

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('members/connectvars.php');

// Connect to the database
require_once('databaseConnection.php'),

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $state = $_POST['state']; 
    $month = $_POST['month']; 
    $year = $_POST['year']; 

    $req = $db->prepare('
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM triathlons 
                 WHERE state = :st 
                 AND month = :mnth 
                 AND year = :yr');

    $req->bindParam(':st', $state, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req->bindParam(':mnth', $month, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $req->bindParam(':yr', $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $req->execute();

    $num = $req->rowCount();
    echo $num . ' results found !<br />';

    while($result = $req->fetch()) {
        $day = $result['day'];
        $date = $result['date'];
        $city = $result['city'];
        $racename = $result['racename'];
        $park = $result['park'];
        $website = $result['website'];

        echo '<br />Day : ' . $day,
             '<br />Last Name : ' . $date,
             '<br />City : ' . $city,
             '<br />Website : ' . $website . '<br />';

    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" id="filtermainpage" action="#">
    <label for="state">State : </label>

    <select name="state" id="state1">
        <option selected="selected" value="">All States</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DC">D.C.</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL" >Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <br />

    <label for="month">Month:</label>
    <select name="month" id="month1">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">All Months</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>


    <label for="year">Year:</label>
    <select name="year" id="year1">
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

---

### Inside the databaseConnection.php file :

```
try {
    $pdo_options = array();
    //Optional
    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $pdo_options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = "SET NAMES utf8";

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';
                         dbname=' . DB_NAME, 
                         DB_USER, 
                         DB_PASSWORD, 
                         $pdo_options);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

You can by the way put the database identifiers in the databaseConnection.php file

Answer (score 0):

Security: please don't just use $_POST['foo'] in your sql, validate that they're values you expect as it opens your system up to many attacks.

Action is now optional in your form as you're submitting to the same page.

You're also missing a } after your if (!$dbc) trigger_error, so either add the } or remove the { after the if condition because as the instruction inside the if is only one line, braces are optional.

Comment: Ok I will make sure I do that Thanks